# What is causing my code to freeze? I am out of ideas

Tags: java

I am working on a game engine in Java, and I am still trying to learn how to properly make a GUI. The way my code works (or, at least, how I want it to work) is I have a class called Main and a class called BattleFrame. BattleFrame has a method that resets System output to a textfield within it. BattleFrame contains the GUI, while Main controls what happens when a button is pressed and the event order in the game. Inside of main, there is a method that loads the game world based on previous save data, stored in text files. When main starts, it calls BattleFrame, which loads in a form that has only one button, continue (I will add new game later). When the user presses continue, actionPerformed will go to Main and then it should print out "Hello". Then it reacts to the fact that the button pressed was continue, and loads the world. This is where the problem happens, since when I remove it, "Hello" gets printed to the text field, but when the method is there, the gui freezes.

Through debugging I discovered that the method everything freezes at is the initialization of class Player in the Load class. After I call player = new Player(name) (the name is read from a text file earlier and is correct), the debugger itself stops. At this point, I am out of ideas why this is happening. Loading the player had previously worked, until I started messing with the Main class and before I started working on the gui, so I suspect the problem must be somewhere there, but I really don't know. Sorry in advance for my ugly code, I know I still have a lot of learning to do in the department of writing something that is understandable.

```
public class Main {

    static World world;
    static Player player;
    static Clerks c;

    static BattleFrame bf;
    static InputCheckers i;
    static Species species;
    static Load l;
    static Specie bear;
    static Shop sh;

    static Save s;
    static Battle b;

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, UnsupportedLookAndFeelException, InterruptedException 
    {

        c = new Clerks();

        species = new Species();

        bear = species.getBasicBear();
        sh = new Shop(c.getFirstClerk());

        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    bf = new BattleFrame();
                    JTextAreaOutputStream out = new JTextAreaOutputStream(bf.textOut);
                    System.setOut(new PrintStream(out));
                    bf.setVisible(true);
                } 
                catch (InterruptedException ex) 
                {
                    Logger.getLogger(Main.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                }

            }
        });
   }

    public void perform(JButton e) throws IOException 
       {
           System.out.println("Po");
           String button = e.getName();
           if(button.equals("continue"))
           {

               newGameOrContinue("c");
           }
           else if(button.equals("new game"))
           {
               System.out.println("    ");
               newGameOrContinue("n");
           }
       }

    public static void newGameOrContinue(String nOrC) throws IOException 
    {

        System.out.println("Hello");
        if (nOrC.equals("c")) {
            Load l = new Load();

            try{
            world = l.loadWorld();
            }
            catch(IOException a)
            {
                System.out.println("WTF");
            }
   }
```

```
public class BattleFrame extends JFrame{

    int mod = 50;


    Main m = new Main();
    public JButton con;
    public JButton newGame;

    boolean pressed = false;

    JScrollPane scroller = new JScrollPane();

    public JTextArea textOut;

    JTextArea textIn;

    JPanel basePanel;

    JTextAreaOutputStream out;

    static GraphicsConfiguration gc;

    public BattleFrame() throws InterruptedException 
    {
        super("Battle Window");
        this.m = m;
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setSize(24 * mod, 20 * mod);
        setLayout(null);
        setBackground(Color.yellow);
        baseFrame();
        setVisible(true);
        System.out.println("Welcome, warrior! Would you like to continue your adventure, or shall you start fresh?\n");
    }

    private void baseFrame() 
    {
        this.baseTextOut();
        this.basePanel();
        this.add(basePanel);
        this.add(textOut);
    }

    private void baseTextOut() 
    {
        textOut = new JTextArea();
        textOut.setForeground(Color.RED);
        textOut.setBackground(Color.BLACK);
        textOut.setFont(new Font("Serif", Font.ITALIC, 16));
        textOut.setLineWrap(true);
        textOut.setWrapStyleWord(true);
        textOut.setEditable(false);
        textOut.setBounds(0, 0, 24 * mod, 18 * mod);
        textOut.setVisible(true);
        out = new JTextAreaOutputStream(textOut);
        System.setOut(new PrintStream(out));
    }

    private void basePanel() 
    {
        basePanel = new JPanel();
        basePanel.setBounds(0, 18 * mod, 24 * mod, 4 * mod);
        basePanel.setBackground(Color.GRAY);
        con = new JButton("Continue");
        con.setName("continue");
        con.setForeground(Color.RED);
        con.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                try {
                    m.perform(con);
                } catch (IOException ex) {
                    Logger.getLogger(BattleFrame.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                }
            }
        });
        basePanel.add(con);

    }
}
```

```
public class Load 
{
    Attacks attacks = new Attacks(0,0);
    Items items = new Items();
    Bodyparts bodyparts = new Bodyparts(0,0);
    Inventory inv = new Inventory();

    public World loadWorld() throws IOException
    {

        Player player = loadPlayer();
        World world = new World(player);
        return world;
    }

    public Player loadPlayer() throws IOException
    {
        String name;
        Player player;
        name = loadName();



        player = new Player(name);//This is the place where the debugger stops
        .
        .
        .
        .
         return player;
    }

    public String loadName() throws FileNotFoundException, IOException
    {
        String location = (System.getProperty("user.dir") + "\\src\\main\\java\\cz\\com\\GameFiles\\Save\\Name.txt");
        File file = new File(location); 

        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file)); 

        String name = br.readLine(); 
        br.close();
        return name;
    }
}
```

```
public class Player extends Object 
{
    protected static Species species = new Species();
    protected Specie human = species.getBasicHuman();
    protected int maxHealth;
    protected int speed;
    protected int str;
    protected Double luck;
    protected int def;
    protected int currentHealth;
    protected int wealth;
    final static protected String name = nameSetter();

    public Player() {
       super(name, "Player Controlled", System.getProperty("user.dir") + "src\\main\\java\\cz\\com\\GameFiles\\LevyBuild\\Sprites\\Objects\\Items\\Misc\\BearClaw.png");
      properties();

    }

    public Player(String givenName) 
    {
         super(givenName, "Player Controlled", System.getProperty("user.dir")+ "src\\main\\java\\cz\\com\\GameFiles\\LevyBuild\\Sprites\\Objects\\Items\\Misc\\BearClaw.png");
         properties();
    }

   public static String nameSetter() 
   {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Please enter player name: ");
        String name = sc.nextLine();
        return name;
   }

   private void properties() 
   {

        this.maxHealth = human.getHP();
        this.speed = human.getSpeed()*2; 
        this.str = human.getStr()*2;   
        this.luck = human.getLuck();      
        this.def = human.getDef();   
        this.currentHealth = maxHealth;       
        this.wealth = 0;
   } 
}
```

```
public abstract class Object 
{
    protected String name; 
    protected String status;
    protected String spriteLocation;

public Object(String giveName, String giveStatus, String giveSpriteLocation)
    {
        name = giveName;
        status = giveStatus;
        spriteLocation = giveSpriteLocation;
    }
}
```

```
public class Species {

        ArrayList<Specie> allSpecies = new ArrayList<Specie> ();

    Randomness rand = new Randomness();

    public Specie getBasicHuman()
    {
        String name = "Basic Human";
        int health  = 50;
        int speed = 5;
        int str = 5;
        Double luck = 0.06;
        int def = 1;
        Attacks allAttacks = new Attacks(health,def);
        Attack[] attacks = new Attack[]{allAttacks.getDoNothing(), allAttacks.getOnePunch()};
        Items items = new Items(health, def);
        Item[] loot = new Item[]{items.getApple()};

        for(Attack attack : attacks)
        {
            attack.setLevel(10);
        }

        Specie basicHuman = new Specie("Basic Human", str, speed, luck, def, health, loot, attacks,"random");
        allSpecies.add(basicHuman);
        return basicHuman;
    }
}
```

```
public class Specie extends Object{

    protected int str;//Strength
    protected int speed;
    protected Double luck;
    protected int def;//Defense
    protected int hp;//Health Points
    protected Item[] loot; //What loot will be possible
    protected Attack[] attacks;
    protected int givenExp;
    protected int levelAttacks = 1;
    protected String focus;

    public Specie(String givenName, int giveStr, int giveSpeed, Double giveLuck, int giveDef, int giveHP, Item[] giveLoot, Attack[] giveAttacks, String giveFocus) {
        super(givenName);
        properties(giveStr,giveSpeed,giveLuck,giveDef,giveHP,giveLoot,giveAttacks, giveFocus);

    }
}
```

What I currently want is for the code to just not freeze, and the text that should be printed out to be printed out. Again, sorry for this mess of a code, trust me, I am doing my best. I tried putting only the necessary parts if the code here, if the formatting is wrong, I will change it, this is my first time asking a question here. Thanks in advance!

Comment: hi, do you really have dots in your code? under `player = new Player(name);//This is the place where the debugger stops`

Comment: Another thing is `public class Player extends Object` you dont need explicitly do it, every custom object (class) automatically inherit object class, anyway, in the given code, you are calling `Player` constructor, but there you have only super, which calls `Object` constructor, but `Object` is [not having constructor as like that](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html)

Comment: if your parent class is called `Object` then its really bad practice, and depends what are you doing with parameters there, otherwise - in case there is not any - code should fail, because there is only default constructor without parameters - `Object(String a,String b)` does not exists in the given code

Comment: Does the code compile? If so what is `human` that you read from in the `properties` method?

Comment: Please learn about java naming conventions. All class names should go UpperCase. And yes: do not re-use names, such as Object for your own classes.

Comment: And long story short: please ensure that you follow [mcve]. Use the [edit] link to improve your question (do not add more information via comments). Otherwise we are not able to answer your question and help you.

Comment: @xxxvodnikxxx No, I added the dots to show that the class has much more code, but I don't think it is relevant to my problem. My code is long enough as is.  You're right, I will rename the class Object to something like "Generic". Its point is so that I don't have to define the name and sprite location for each new game object (not code, I really should have picked a better name). So you think that simply changing (and refractoring) the class name may fix the problem? Thanks for the response!

Comment: @Joakim Danielson  It compiles, but freezes after pressing continue. Human is from a class that just stores variables. I should have included it, sorry. Still, I doubt that it causes the freezing issue

Comment: Renaming probably do not fix the problem, but it will be more proper code than current :), but the whole code is inconsistent .. 
You are calling constructor which doesnt exists (via super as mentioned), then you call `parameters()` without any parameter (should be called something like `setParameters` btw, and then inside you are referring into `human` variable, that's taken from where? Etc..

Comment: `Human is from a class that just stores variables` well, but you are not passing the value anywhere like method arg eg., or its being created before somewhere, etc...

Comment: actually , with `super(givenName, "Player Controlled", "user.dir" + "src\\main\\java\\cz\\com\\GameFiles\\LevyBuild\\Sprites\\Objects\\Items\\Misc\\BearClaw.png");`, you are trying to call constructor from your `Object` class - `Object(String name,String status,String path)` or similar- whatever should last parameter mean - , which takes 3 Strings as input arguments, but it looks like it doesnt exist (at least not in code which you showed), then I am not sure how you got your code compiled :)

Comment: @xxxvodnikxxx sorry, the object class has overloading, I will edit the original post to reflect this :)

Comment: Ok, thanks, in this case it looks all fine for me, just one stupid question- did not you got stuck because of breakpoint of debugger? :)

Comment: @xxxvodnikxxx That is a good point, I will look

Comment: @xxxvodnikxxx Just checked, the breakpoint was further down. Really, the moment it hits player = new Player(name), it just stops. Renaming it also didn't solve the problem, but thanks for the tip regardless, at least the code will make more sense :)

Comment: `"user.dir" + "...` misses `System.getProperty("user.dir")`. Which xxxvodnikxxx probably wanted to mention also.

Comment: @JoopEggen Thanks, I fixed it, but that didn't solve the problem either, though I am sure It saved me from future errors :)

Comment: `protected Specie human = species.getBasicHuman();`, `getBasicHuman()` is a void method so any access to human should generate a null pointer exception? _EDIT I now see the method is named `basicHuman()` without the "get" so it is not the method used and the one used is not included in the question..._

Comment: @JoakimDanielson Sorry, this is, again, my inexperience with naming coming into play. getBasicHuman returns the Specie BasicHuman, while BasicHuman() simply sets it. I will add it to the posted code

Comment: When you call `basicHuman()` you create a new `Specie` object and assign it to the instance variable `basicHuman` and then this variable is added to a list. Next time you call `basicHuman()` you assign a new  `Specie` object to the same instance variable  `basicHuman` and add this new version of the variable to the list so now you have two instances of this variable in the list. Not sure if this is what causes the freeze but it is _definitely_ wrong.

Comment: continued comment (was too long):  I would remove `basicHuman` as an instance variable and let the `basicHuman()` method return a new `Specie` object instead (and add it to the list as before) so the list contains each individual `Specie` object created.

Comment: @JoakimDanielson Thanks for pointing that out, I changed it so that now there is only a getBasicHuman() there, without the variable. Unfortunately, even this didn't fix the problem. Also, I am a bit concerned that now basic human will be added to the specie list each time I call it, which might cause problems, since basicHuman will be the Specie of most NPC characters. I'll think about that later, though. First I need the gui to work :)

Comment: Are you trying to add components to your JFrame directly? I think you should add them to `JFrame.getContentPane()`.
You also disabled the layout manager. This means, you will have to arrange the components yourself. I suggest you take a look at BorderLayout. Having the battlefield in the center and the test out in the south sounds reasonable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Function `nameSetter()` gets called before `Player` applies the constructor and static function `nameSetter()` requires user input, which you have disabled in `BattleWindow`, so the program waits for user input that will never happen. Just change `Player` constructor to the following:

```
public class Player extends GameObject {

  protected static Equipment equipped = new Equipment();
  protected static Species species = new Species();
  protected Specie human = species.getBasicHuman();
  protected int maxHealth;
  protected int speed;
  protected int str;
  protected Double luck;
  protected int def;
  protected int currentHealth;
  protected int wealth;

  Inventory inv = new Inventory();

  public Player() {
    super(Player.nameSetter(), "Player Controlled", System.getProperty("user.dir") + "src\\main\\java\\cz\\com\\GameFiles\\LevyBuild\\Sprites\\Objects\\Items\\Misc\\BearClaw.png");
    properties();
  }
}
```

Be aware that whenever you create new instance of `Player` it will crash again. You need to enable user input again.